# How to scroll in browser with Logitech Trackman Marble?

Tags: mac, scrolling, logitech-mouse, trackball

I have a Logitech Trackman Marble and I really love it. I spend a lot of time on web browser and code editors. I was wondering if there could be a feature like when I press Option Key the trackball becomes a scroll wheel. So that I can use the trackball for both moving cursor and scrolling.

Comment: Possible duplicates: [remedy for a no scroll wheel trackball?](http://superuser.com/questions/303661/remedy-for-a-no-scroll-wheel-trackball?rq=1), [Scroll modifier for mouse/trackball in windows](http://superuser.com/questions/498198/scroll-modifier-for-mouse-trackball-in-windows)

Comment: @techie007 Thanks! The first question you mentioned seemed to be what I was trying to do. But there wasn't a solution for Mac:(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [KeyRemap4MacBook](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en):

```
<autogen>__PointingRelativeToScroll__ PointingButton::NONE, ModifierFlag::FN | ModifierFlag::NONE</autogen>
```

Replace ModifierFlag::FN with VK_CONTROL for either control. Keys that aren't modifier keys can be mapped to EXTRA1:

```
<autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::F1, KeyCode::VK_MODIFIER_EXTRA1</autogen>
<autogen>__PointingRelativeToScroll__ PointingButton::NONE, ModifierFlag::EXTRA1</autogen>
```

Key Repeat > [Pointing Device] CursorMove to ScrollWheel Rate changes the scrolling speed.

See the source for the [key code values](https://github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/blob/master/src/bridge/generator/keycode/data/KeyCode.data) and [predefined settings](http://raw.github.com/tekezo/KeyRemap4MacBook/master/Tests/lib/string/data/checkbox.xml).

Comment: Thanks! KeyRemap4MacBook does exactly what I needed. I'm using Fn+CursorMove to ScrollWheel:)